# how to fix this unexpected mix of '>>>' and '&' operators warning?

Tags: javascript, base64, eslint

I am trying to use a Base64 encoding and decoding utility script in my react app. I get this warning on this line. It is working fine but I don't want it and I don't want to disable EsLint for this warning.

Could you help me which parts needs grouping?

```
  for (nMod3 = 0; nMod3 < 3 && nOutIdx < nOutLen; nMod3++, nOutIdx++) {
            taBytes[nOutIdx] = nUint24 >>> (16 >>> nMod3 & 24) & 255;
        }
```

Comment: Consider using the browser's native base64 encoding/decoding, it might be sufficient? If this is your own code, not a dependency (since you're linting it), I'd say putting a eslint exception for `no-mixed-operators` in there is perfectly legitimate. The eslint rule might complain because there is some bitwise logic happening that's possibly optimized and therefore a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either follow the advice and make [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) explicit:

```
taBytes[nOutIdx] = (nUint24 >>> ((16 >>> nMod3) & 24)) & 255;
```

... or disable the [no-mixed-operators](http://no-mixed-operators) rule.